# If div id contains text, remove class from another div (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make months appear as posts are published by reading the div with the id **blog-date-read** for the and removing the display none class on the divs around each month, i.e. **Feb2016CC**.

The blog date appears like this:

```
<div class="blog-date blog-date-2" id="blog-date-read">Feb 2016</div>
```

The blog months look like this:

```
<div id="FebCC2016" class="display-none-blog">
<p><a href="#">Feb 2016</a></p>
</div>
```

And the jQuery I have attempted looks like this:

```
if ($("div#blog-date-read:contains('Feb 2016')")) {
$("#FebCC2016").removeClass("display-none-blog");
}
```

I'm sure I've missed something with my jQuery, but I can't tell what. Can someone point me in the right direction with this?

**EDIT:**

If anyone else comes across this in the future, I ended up using this solution:

```
if ($(".blog-date-2").text().indexOf("Feb 2016") >= 0) {
    $("#FebCC2016").removeClass("display-none-blog");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `-read` in `#blog-date-read` in your ID selector :

```
if ($("div#blog-date-read:contains('Feb 2016')")) {
  $("#FebCC2016").removeClass("display-none-blog");
}
```

Comment: I've updated this, but unfortunately it's still not working for me. ):

Comment: Must be noted that text inside `:contains` is case sensitive and one more thing, do you have more than one element using this `id="blog-date-read"` id name?

Comment: I realised that each time the date appears it was using the same id, so yes. I tried to use this: div.blog-date-2:contains('Feb 2016') searching each div with the class attached with no luck.

Comment: Then, only first matched element are returned if you're using more than one element for one ID name. And for this `$("#FebCC2016")` element also same. Never use same id name

Comment: Yes, I have removed this and tried doing it by divs with the blog-date-2 class but it does not work either.

Comment: I meant for this `$("#FebCC2016")` element. Do you have same ID for other element, or only just this one. See this answer https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/5pvz1Lnw/ . The border should be the red

Comment: I copied the jQuery from your JSFiddle and it appears to be working now, thank you! But yes, each month had it's own unique ID. I'm not sure what happened, but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert($("div.blog-date").text())
if ($("div.blog-date").text().toLowerCase() == 'feb 2016') {
$("#FebCC2016").removeClass("display-none-blog");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-date blog-date-2" id="blog-date-read">Feb 2016</div>


<div id="FebCC2016" class="display-none-blog">
<p><a href="#">Feb 2016</a></p>
</div>
```

First change the `#` from you condition to `.` because it is a class then use `text()` to get the content try this way.

Comment: I get the alert, but it does not remove the class.

Comment: check the dev tools the class is gone @Trees

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on the page. Again, it does not remove the class, only returns the alert. What could this mean?

Comment: the condition is not met did you check the text that was in the condition if it is the same in the alert. it should be the same. @Trees you will always get the alert because it is outside the condition

Comment: @Trees add `.toLowerCase()` on the condition and also make the other side all lowercase so that they will be equal